# Как средствами PHP узнать имена (имя) таблиц БД?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как средствами php узнать имена (имя) таблиц БД?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query('show tables');
```

Штудируйте мануал mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `table`;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное средство:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'base table' and table_schema='имя базы'
```

Будет работать везде кроме Оракла. :-)